# Facebook API: user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions

Tags: facebook, authentication, session, permissions

Please look at the example below:

Now while scenarios #1 and #3 are quite obvious, my question is:

Is it possible that scenario #2 is valid ? i.e Connected - But no permissions given?

Thanks.

--

Code:

```
FB.login(function(response) {  
  if (response.session) {  
     if (response.perms) {  
        // #1 user is logged in and granted some permissions.  
       } else {  
       // #2 user is not logged in OR user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions   
     }  
   } else {  
    // #3 user is not logged in  
  }  
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe #2 occurs if the user has previously approved your app, but now you need more scope / permissions (such as email, publish_stream etc) and they haven't yet approved those new scopes. So the way you have the code posted, no it won't occur because you aren't asking for additional permissions. But if you added {perms:'publish_stream'} as the last parameter to the [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) function, it might occur.